# Removing new line if last character is comma

Tags: unix

Hi I'm trying to manipulate a report generated with nsradmin (networker) 
By the way this is a simple output (there are about 5000 lines)

```
                   name: SERVER1;
                   group: FIRST;
                save set: "C:\\", "VSS SYSTEM FILESET:\\", "VSS OTHER:\\",
                          "VSS USER DATA:\\", "VSS SYSTEM SERVICES:\\",
                          "VSS SYSTEM BOOT:\\";
          client OS type: Windows NT Server on Intel;
       NetWorker version: 7.4.4.Build.634;


                    name: SERVER2;
                   group: NGDC_SO_5;
                group: NGDC_SO_5;
                          "VSS OTHER:\\", "VSS USER DATA:\\",
                          "VSS SYSTEM SERVICES:\\", "VSS SYSTEM BOOT:\\",
                          "C:\\";
                           client OS type: Windows NT Server on Intel;
                         NetWorker version: 7.4.4.Build.634;
```

I'd like a report in this format

```
name: SERVER1;group: NGDC_SO_5;VSS OTHER:\\", "VSS USER DATA:\\"client OS type: Windows NT Server on Intel;

name: SERVER2;group: NGDC_SO_5;VSS OTHER:\\", "VSS USER DATA:\\"client OS type: Windows NT Server on Intel;
```

The First Line  always starting with NAME ,the last is "a blank line  .
Unfortunately I  try but I did not succeed

Comment: show us what you tried

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` to merge lines between `name`:

```
awk '/name/{if (x)print x;x="";}{x=(!x)?$0:x","$0;}END{print x;}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very quick and dirty stab to see if it's close to what you're looking for

```
awk '
""    {print saved; saved=""; next}
      {saved = saved " " $0}
END   {print saved}
' filename
```

You can refine it innumerable ways